# Cypress function randomly times out "promise that never resolved."

Tags: javascript, authentication, cypress

I'm overwriting the visit command to run tests on our QA environment which requires authentication. Most of the time it works fine but sometimes it fails with

> cy.then() timed out after waiting 4000ms.
>
> Your callback function returned a promise that never resolved.

My function is:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite("visit", (originalFn, url, options) => {
  // Read the auth details from accounts.json
  cy.fixture("accounts").then((account) => {
    const username = account.auth_username;
    const password = account.auth_password;

    const authenticatedOptions = {
      ...options,
      auth: { username, password },
      failOnStatusCode: false,
    };

    return originalFn(url, authenticatedOptions);
  });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong to make it flakey?

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? It's returning the result of `originalFn` but then `cy.fixture` return value is not being used?

Comment: authenticatedOptions gets passed to the originalFN, it contains the auth username and password the site asks for when you visit it. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Add-basic-auth-headers it's doing that but instead of passing it in each time I call visit I overwrite the function to do it automatically

Comment: How does cypress know when the promise is complete? This is probably why it times out

Comment: I'm not sure, according to the documents it should never time out when calling .fixture https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Timeouts

Comment: Something that looks shady is that you `return` from the `.then()` callback, but you don't return that promise from the `overwrite` callback, so `visit` won't know it should wait for the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting commands can be a bit dodgy, the behavior when calling `originalFn()` is not always the same as when calling as a command, e.g `cy.visit()`.

The failure is likely because the visit failed (i.e the call `originalFn(url, authenticatedOptions)` failed for some reason). But `originalFn()` returns a Promise, which should be rejected on failure but it isn't.

When you call a bad URL, say `cy.visit('http://example-not-valid.com')`, without the overwrite Cypress gives you a fairly decent message. With the overwrite it's just an unresolved promise.

You could use composition and add a new command

```
Cypress.Commands.add("visitWithAuthentication", (url, options) => {

  cy.fixture("accounts").then((account) => {
    const username = account.auth_username;
    const password = account.auth_password;

    const authenticatedOptions = {
      ...options,
      auth: { username, password },
      failOnStatusCode: false,
    };

    cy.visit(url, authenticatedOptions);
  });
});
```

This will give you the correct message, but may not be convenient when switching from DEV to QA environments.